# Bootstrap responsive embed YouTube not working in Safari desktop

Tags: video, youtube, safari, embed

I've been using this snippet for ages to embed YouTube videos into my site, but it doesn't work any more in Safari (10.0.2 desktop), see the link above.  Any idea how to make it work?:

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Which is from bootstrap's docs:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed